# Defining a table with sqlalchemy with a mysql unix timestamp

Tags: python, mysql, sqlalchemy

Background, there are several ways to store dates in MySQ.

1. As a string e.g. "09/09/2009".
2. As integer using the function UNIX_TIMESTAMP() this is supposedly the traditional unix time representation (you know seconds since the epoch plus/minus leap seconds).
3. As a MySQL TIMESTAMP, a mysql specific data type not the same than unix timestamps.
4. As a MySQL Date field, another mysql specific data type.

   It's very important not to confuse case 2 with case 3 (or case 4).
   I have an existing table with an integer date field (case 2) how can I define it in sqlalchemy in a way I don't have to access mysql's "FROM_UNIXTIME" function?

   For the record, just using sqlalchemy.types.DateTime and hoping it does the right thing when it detects an integer column doesn't work, it works for timestamp fields and date fields.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think there is a couple of issues with the type decorator you showed.

1. `impl` should be `sqlalchemy.types.Integer` instead of `DateTime`.
2. The decorator should allow nullable columns.

Here's the what I have in mind:

```
import datetime, time
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, DateTime, Integer

class IntegerDateTime(TypeDecorator):
    """a type that decorates DateTime, converts to unix time on
    the way in and to datetime.datetime objects on the way out."""
    impl = Integer # In schema, you want these datetimes to
                   # be stored as integers.
    def process_bind_param(self, value, _):
        """Assumes a datetime.datetime"""
        if value is None:
            return None # support nullability
        elif isinstance(value, datetime.datetime):
            return int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))
        raise ValueError("Can operate only on datetime values. "
                         "Offending value type: {0}".format(type(value).__name__))
    def process_result_value(self, value, _):
        if value is not None: # support nullability
            return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value))
```

Comment: Ok I like it, a shame this didn't make it to production in the end. But why did you replace engine with _?

Comment: Just a habit. pylint dislikes unused variables, so by convention we use _.

Answer (score 3):

So yeah, this approach works. And I ended up answering my own question :/, hope somebody finds this useful.

```
import datetime, time
from sqlalchemy.types import TypeDecorator, DateTime
class IntegerDateTime(TypeDecorator):
    """a type that decorates DateTime, converts to unix time on
    the way in and to datetime.datetime objects on the way out."""
    impl = DateTime
    def process_bind_param(self, value, engine):
        """Assumes a datetime.datetime"""
        assert isinstance(value, datetime.datetime)
        return int(time.mktime(value.timetuple()))
    def process_result_value(self, value, engine):
        return datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(float(value))
    def copy(self):
        return IntegerDateTime(timezone=self.timezone)
```